# hadoop.tmp.dir not being respected from hadoop command

Tags: hadoop

How is the `hadoop.tmp.dir` set on the command line?  I have tried to add it by adding it to the command line - and when that did not work also via the `HADOOP_OPTS`:

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dhadoop.tmp.dir=/tmp/tmp

That directory was created specifically for the purpose of being world writable:

```
$ls -lrta /tmp/tmp
total 0
drwxrwxrwx   2 myuser   wheel    64 Apr 27 01:23 .
drwxrwxrwt  45 root     wheel  1440 Apr 27 01:23 ..
```

But `hadoop` continues to use whatever default `tmpdir` it wants to:

```
$hadoop jar target/mp5-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner -Dmapreduce.child.java.opts="-Dhadoop.tmpdir=/tmp/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tp/tmp" ConnectedComponentsComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IntIntNullTextInputFormat -vip dataset/graph.data -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op file://$(pwd)/output/part-a -w 1 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false
```

But always we end up with permission errors;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 
Mkdirs failed to create /var/folders/3t/4d3czfm17fb2v9z_m8rvflyrg8jmdl/T/hadoop-unjar2119053878070751096/META-INF/license
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.ensureDirectory(RunJar.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.unJar(RunJar.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.unJar(RunJar.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
```

So how to configure hadoop on the command line or at least via env vars (not by changing the `hadoop` config files themselves) ?

(Btw I *also* set that in the `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml` .. *still* no dice)

```
$grep  -C 2 hadoop.tmp.dir $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/tmp</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: Check with this command whether hadoop temp directory is set or not. 

`hdfs getconf -confKey hadoop.tmp.dir`

Comment: `/tmp/tmp` .  Nice info on that command in any case.